# Django - Using ChainedModelChoiceField (smart_selects)

Tags: python, django

I am using smart_selects in Django to filter drop down views.
In my admin page, I was successful in doing this using 'ChainedForeignKey'

I am now trying to create a user form and implement the same thing with 'ChainedModelChoiceField'

Basically I am trying access my model data on a form so that when a user selects a 'State', only cities in that state appear. My models are already populated as well.

models.py:

```
class State(models.Model):
    state= models.CharField(max_length=140)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.state

class City(models.Model):
    city= models.CharField(max_length=140,unique=True)
    state= models.ForeignKey(State)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField, ModelForm
from smart_selects.form_fields import ChainedModelChoiceField
from search.models import State, City

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    user_state = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = State.objects.all(),required=True)
    user_city=ChainedModelChoiceField( ..
```

//html page

```
{% block title %}Contact - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

the 'city' drop down just appears blank.
I see that the args for ChainedModelChoiceField are:

> self, to_app_name, to_model_name, chained_field,
>   chained_model_field,foreign_key_app_name, foreign_key_model_name,
>   foreign_key_field_name,show_all, auto_choose, sort=True, manager=None,
>   initial=None, view_name=None

Answer (score 1):

Solved this.

After multiple attempts of trying to implement *ChainedModelChoiceField*, it turns out the the client side jQuery was giving me an issue.

What you have to do:
Make sure this is the **first** thing after "% load static files...":

```
  <script src="{% static 'xxxxx/xxxx/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'smart-selects/admin/js/chainedfk.js' %}"></script>
```